# React-router: can't forward user to other page outside of component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React 0.13.3 with react-router 1.0.0-rc3.

I am trying to forward the user to a different page on login / logout, but always get the error "_servicesRouterContainer2.default.get(...).transitionTo is not a function".

My code looks like this (irrelevant parts omitted):

In app.js I set up the routes:

```jsx
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import RouterContainer from './services/RouterContainer';

let routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Master}>
      <Route path="some-component" component={SomeComponent}/>
      <Route path="login" component={LoggedOut}/>
      <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
RouterContainer.set(routes);

React.render(RouterContainer.get(), document.body);
```

The routes are then stored in RouterContainer:

```jsx
var _router = null;
export default {
  set: (router) => _router = router,
  get: () => _router
};
```

Now I am trying to transition the user to a different page when LoginActions.loginUser / LoginActions.logoutUser is called:

```jsx
import RouterContainer from '../services/RouterContainer';

export default {
  loginUser: (response) => {
    ...

    let nextPath = RouterContainer.get().getCurrentQuery().nextPath || '/';
    RouterContainer.get().transitionTo(nextPath);
  },

  logoutUser: () => {
    ...

    RouterContainer.get().transitionTo('login');
  }
};
```

The transition is not working and my console shows the error "_servicesRouterContainer2.default.get(...).transitionTo is not a function".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

React Router 1.0 does not use `transitionTo` anymore. Please see the [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md) which will let you see the changes between 0.13.x and 1.0

you should use the History module together with React Router 1.0 to solve your problem:

```jsx
this.history.pushState(null, path)
```

See the [**transitions** app](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/examples/transitions/app.js) for a full example of use.

Comment: The upgrade guide and transition app links are dead